# Urdu Input in the text box

Tags: vb.net, regional-settings

I want to build an application, in which text boxes can take urdu language.  I tried changing the font and put it to Arabic but when I ran it and typed something, it types in English.

I do not want user to change regional setting when my application is used.
I have seen this in many urdu applications, when we install, we simply run them without changing any settings.

Please advise how to do it?

Thanks 
Furqan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Furqan you must have specified your development language ,is it java or C# or ..
Well what I can think of is that you can make a static Class which has English to Urdu character mappings and whenever a user types a character you handle it in the "Character Typed Event Handler" and replace the character with proper Mapping For Example "P" with "پ"..

I hope it gives you a start...